# Why is an untranslated string not showing up?

Tags: i18n-l10n

In my module I have some custom strings. I use these in the `t()` function.
When I go to `admin/config/regional/translate/translate` and filter the untranslated strings my custom strings do not show here.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Please show us your code. We can't debug what we can't see. Read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Did you cleared the cache ? Maybe that's the solution to your problem.

Comment: If code is OK, go to *Home > Administration > Configuration > Regional and language > Translate interface* and simply hit the *Refresh Strings* button. I don't really know if it will help you, hence just a mere comment and  not an answer. But if it'll work, I will add some meat to it and post as answer ;)

Comment: Flush cache saved my life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strings needs to be rendered a first time on a page in the not default language and your string keys will be visible in the `Translate interface`.

An important detail, the search is case sensitive. For example `My text` is different than `my text`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to see the site in English the `t()` function will not try translate the string, so you need to see the site in other language in order to for the translation system to add your translatable string to the database.

Once you do it, you will be able to translate your string.

Answer (score 2):

Beside visiting the page showing your strings in a non-default language, make sure to have the version number of the module set in the .info file.

> version = 7.x-1.0

[Here](http://www.gbyte.co/blog/when-custom-t-strings-are-missing-from-translate-interface) a trouble shooting blog post to getting your strings into the translate interface.