# String passed to the T function in inline_template not accessible for translation

Tags: 8, theming, i18n-l10n

For a custom field I have a formatter:

```
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $elements = [];
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $value = unserialize($item->value);
      $elements[$delta] = [
        '#type' => 'inline_template',
        '#template' => "{{ 'translate_me'|t }} {% for key,value in info %}  {{ key|t }}  : {{ value }} <br/> {% endfor %}",
        '#context' => ['info' => $value],
      ];
    }
    return $elements;
  }
```

I tried to search for the string "translate_me" on `admin/config/regional/translate` to translate it but cannot find it. I did clear the cache, run the cron, ensure the module the define the string has a version, and **viewed the node in the target language**. but to no avail. What am I missing?

Thank

Comment: You have to ensure that this string got displayed in the target language in the frontend at least once to be picked up for translation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is an untranslated string not showing up?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90208/why-is-an-untranslated-string-not-showing-up)

Comment: @leymannx I did that too ... I will update my question.

Comment: Another issue is that variables ain't translatable. `{{ key|t }}` will not work. So you have to find an alternative way or ensure to pass the `key` string already in the right language (via `getTranslationFromContext`) to Twig (presuming it comes from a translated node).

Comment: I thought that variables may not be translatable but how about`{{ 'translate_me'|t }}` trying it in the local_sources table but its not there.  I am trying to suspect the t function does not work in `viewElements` method of a field formatter

Comment: Yeah, I'm having that feeling, too. Suspecting `'#type' => 'inline_template',`. Might be worth an issue on drupal.org. Last resort would be to use `'#type' => 'markup',` and the classic `t('translate_me')` or `$this->t('translate_me')`.

Comment: Why are you even using an inline template here? That's not template content - there is no markup in there. It can all be done in PHP and dumped to #markup, or if you really want to use a template, you should do it properly and create a new theme hook with a template, and call that template rather than inline.

Comment: @leymannx I found the issue. It has to do with language detection and selection configuration at `admin/config/regional/language/detection`. For the T function to work, the language detection and selection for the user interface must be set to `Language from the URL (Path prefix or domain)` . However, I had that setup for content not for interface because I wanted the interface (admin) to only be in english and for content to detect from URL.

Comment: [looks like it maybe be a known issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2189267)

Comment: Nice findings! I think you should make that a proper answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by the configuration for language detection and selection configuration at `admin/config/regional/language/detection`.

For the `t()` function to work, the language detection and selection for the user interface must be set to "*Language from the URL (Path prefix or domain)*". [There is an issue on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2189267) that may address this one.